# R counting rows of dataframes in list: for loop behaves differently from apply?

Tags: r, dataframe

So I came across a very strange problem in writing a convenience function to count the number of rows in each dataframe in a list of dataframes.  I think there must be some basic behavior I'm missing, like indexing over lists doesn't work the way I think it does, or something's getting coerced to the wrong type of variable or something.  Can someone help a brother out?

Reproducible example:

```
myvec <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
df1 <- as.data.frame(rbind(myvec, myvec))
df2 <- as.data.frame(rbind(myvec, myvec, myvec))
dflist <- list(df1, df2)
nrow(dflist[[1]])
# output as expected: [1] 2
nrow(dflist[[2]])
# output as expected: [1] 3

# convenience function 

countrows <- function(pglist) {
  dfsizes <- rep(NA, length(pglist))
  for (i in length(pglist)) {
    dfsizes[i] <- nrow(pglist[[i]])
    return(dfsizes)
  }  
}

newvector <- countrows(dflist)
newvector

# output totally not as expected: [1] NA  3
```

I've gotta be missing something obvious here.

Yes, I know that this could be done perfectly easily with `lapply(dflist, nrow)` --- and that actually does produce the right output.  But clearly I don't know how to loop over the elements of a list properly, and that is a problem totally apart from there being an easier way to do what I'm trying to achieve...

**Edit:** a kind commenter pointed out that I had the return statement inside the for loop, oops.  However, correcting that still produces the same bad output:

```
countrows2 <- function(pglist) {
  dfsizes <- rep(NA, length(pglist))
  for (i in length(pglist)) {
    dfsizes[i] <- nrow(pglist[[i]])
  }  
  return(dfsizes)
}

doom <- countrows2(dflist)
doom
# still bad output: [1] NA  3
```

second edit: I am bad at avoiding stupid syntax errors, like forgetting to start the loop at 1.  Double whoops.  See comments from Neal Fultz, who is less bad at avoiding stupid syntax errors than I am.

Comment: Your return is too early, it exits before the loop finishes.

Comment: However, corrected version with return statement outside the for loop still produces the same bad output.

Comment: Try `1:length(pglist)` in the for loop.

Comment: ooh. yeah. that too.  so many syntax errors, all the syntax errors!  That fixed it.  thanks.

Comment: When I run your example and type `df1`, it gives an error: duplicate rownames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a problem it needs to be 1:length(pglist) not just length(pglist) in the for() part. You looped for i in only length(pglist). Also taking the return expression out of the loop is necessary.

```
countrows <- function(pglist) {
  dfsizes <- rep(NA, length(pglist))
  for (i in 1:length(pglist)) {
    dfsizes[i] <- nrow(pglist[[i]])
  }  
  return(dfsizes)
}

newvector <- countrows(dflist)
newvector
```

This should work as expected now. Cheers

Edit: I am not allowed to comment yet